# NodeJS and SQLite3 check row exist before insert

Tags: node.js, sqlite

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database("items.db");
db.serialize(function()
    {
        var stmt = " SELECT * FROM items;";
        db.get(stmt, function(err, row){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(typeof row == "undefined") {
                    db.prepare("INSERT INTO items (ID) VALUES(?)").run("item1").finalize();
            } else {
                console.log("row is: ", row);
            }
        });
    });
```

The snippet above produces the following error:

```
events.js:72
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: SQLITE_MISUSE: Database handle is closed
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and is this the best way to do this?

I also tried to use:

```
var stmt = " SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM monitor LIMIT 1)";
```

to check if the entry exists or not.

### Thank you,

D

Comment: Which one is line 72? Is it `db.get(stmt, function(err, row){`?

Comment: The thing is that I don't have a file called events.js.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what the problem was.  I had a db.close(); call at the end of the file that I did not pay attention to.  I have yet to get used to things being run asynchronously in node.js.

The events.js file seems to be in the node-sqlite package.

Thank you for all the people who tried to help.

D